# Execute Commands in the Linux Commandline [Lazarus / Free Pascal]

Tags: command-line, lazarus, freepascal

I have a problem. I want to execute some commands in the Commandline of linux. I tested TProcess (So i am using Lazarus) but now when i am starting the programm, there is nothing, wich the Program do.

Here is my Code:

```
uses [...], unix, process;
[...]
var LE_Path: TLabeledEdit;
[...]

Pro1:=TProcess.Create(nil);
Pro1.CommandLine:=(('sudo open'+LE_Path.Text));
Pro1.Options := Pro1.Options;  //Here i used Options before
Pro1.Execute;
```

With this Program, i want to open Files with sudo (The Programm is running on the User Interface)

->Sorry for my Bad English; Sorry for fails in the Question: I am using StackOverflow the first time.

Comment: Thanks! You have the Solution! There was a fail in point 3. (No space afeter open). Have days it sat, and tried, but not this little error found. Tahnks! I tested it and it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the solution was a missing space char?

Change

```
Pro1.CommandLine:=(('sudo open'+LE_Path.Text));
```

to

```
Pro1.CommandLine:=(('sudo open '+LE_Path.Text));
# ----------------------------^--- added this space char.
```

But if you're a beginner programmer, my other comments are still worth considering:

1. trying to use sudo in your first bit of code may be adding a whole extra set of problems. SO... Get something easier to work first, maybe

   /bin/ls -l /path/to/some/dir/that/has/only/a/few/files.
2. find out how to print a statement that will be executed. This is the most basic form of debugging and any language should support that.
3. Your english communicated  your problem well enough, and by including sample code and reasonable (not perfect) problem description "we" were able to help you. In general, a good question contains the fewest number of steps to re-create the problem. OR, if you're trying to manipulate data,

   a. small sample input,
   b. sample output from that same input
   c. your "best" code you have tried
   d. your current output
   e. your thoughts about why it is not working
       AND comments to indicate generally other things you have tried.

Comment: I havent used an Output of the Commmand, because i dont have thinked that the space after the "open" can it be. In Lazarus an little Problem is, that i am cant see so good if there is a space or not. Now i thinked, linux is giving an message if the Process is not complete or is failed. I have an Output of the Process, but it doesent work. I am fixing it now